# Simple Ajax Request with Rails & Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

went through some tutorials on Ajax-Rails. To see if I understood the concepts correctly, I tried doing my own solo Ajax request.

I ran into a roadblock though because I'm only returning an empty [ ] when I do **/forum_threads.json**  I think the issue is in either my controller under index which is as follows.

```
def index
@forum_threads = ForumThread.all
@forum_threads = ForumThread.where(id: :ForumThread_id)
end
```

Or in my super simple json.jbuilder which I did by as such:

```
json.array! @forum_threads do |forum_thread|
json.url forum_thread_path(forum_thread)
end
```

**forum_thread.js.coffee**

```
class Forum_Threads
constructor: ->
    @forum_threads = $("[data-behavior='forum_threads']")
setup: ->
    $.ajax(
        url:"/forum_threads.json"
        dataType: "JSON"
        method: "GET"
        success: @handleSuccess
    )
handleSuccess: (data) =>
    items = $.map data, (forum_thread) ->
        "<p class='item' href='#{forum_thread.url}'></p>"
    $("[data-behavior='forum_thread-items']").html(items)
jQuery ->
new Forum_Threads
```

**Index.html.erb**

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#trending">Trending</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#westoros">Westoros</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#essos">Essos</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#wall">Beyond the Wall</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
<div id="trending" class="tab-pane fade in active" data-behavior="forum_threads">
<h3>Trending</h3>
  <p class="item" data-behavior="forum_thread-items"></p>
</div>
<div id="westoros" class="tab-pane fade">
  <h3>Westeros</h3>
  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
<div id="essos" class="tab-pane fade">
  <h3>Essos</h3>
  <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
</div>
<div id="wall" class="tab-pane fade">
  <h3>Beyond the Wall</h3>
  <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
</div>
```

If you can help me out would be super helpful. Thank you so much guys :)

Github to the Code: https://github.com/OmarZV/NotificationAjax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with the help of a professional developer I was able to tackle what was wrong with my code. I've put down the correct help me here in case anyone else runs into a similar issue. The problem was 4 fold: Turbolinks, my controller file for forum_threads, index.json.jbuilder, and my coffescript file. Hope it helps someone else learning.

Index.json.jbuilder

```
json.array! @forum_threads do |forum_thread|
json.title forum_thread.title
json.url forum_thread_path(forum_thread)
end
```

forum_threads_controller.rb

```
class ForumThreadsController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
before_action :set_forum_thread, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
def index
@forum_threads = ForumThread.all
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json
end
  end
```

**forum_threads.js.coffee**

```
class ForumThreads
constructor: ->
    @forum_threads = $("[data-behavior='forum_threads']")
    @setup()


setup: ->
    $.ajax(
        url:"/forum_threads.json"
        dataType: "JSON"
        method: "GET"
        success: @handleSuccess
    )


handleSuccess: (data) =>
    console.log data
    items = $.map data, (forum_thread) ->
        "<p><a class='item' href='#{forum_thread.url}'>#{forum_thread.title}</a></p>"
    $("[data-behavior='forum_thread-items']").html(items)
$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
new ForumThreads
```

**Index.html.erb**

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#trending">Trending</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#westoros">Westoros</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#essos">Essos</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#wall">Beyond the Wall</a></li>
</ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
<div id="trending" class="tab-pane fade in active" data-behavior="forum_threads">
  <h3>Trending</h3>   
  <p class="item" data-behavior="forum_thread-items"></p>
</div>
<div id="westoros" class="tab-pane fade">
  <h3>Westeros</h3>
  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
<div id="essos" class="tab-pane fade">
  <h3>Essos</h3>
  <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
</div>
<div id="wall" class="tab-pane fade">
  <h3>Beyond the Wall</h3>
  <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@forum_threads = ForumThread.all #hare you are loading all ForumThread records 
@forum_threads = ForumThread.where(id: :ForumThread_id) # ForumThread has no integer key?
```

so try to do this:

```
ForumThread.where(id: [1, 2]) or something like this.
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, I was able to get /forum_threads.json to show results for 1 & 2. However on my HTML page the results are not being displayed even though I think I've correctly labeled data-behavior. I've put the relevant HTML here in the comment as well.
<div class="tab-content">
<div id="trending" class="tab-pane fade in active" data-behavior="forum_threads">
<h3>Trending</h3>
  <p class="item" data-behavior="forum_thread-items"></p>
</div>

Comment: also you can run "rails console" and try to exec your code there. Console will show you what method returns